# Why are mouse events not raised by my custom user control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls

I want to create a composite custom control with trackbar and others that will be used by some client forms. I need to expose some events like `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` to detect start of drag and end of drag. Weirdly, `MouseDown` is OK but not `MouseUp`. The code below demonstrates it. Is this a bug in the .NET Framework or of the trackbar? If not, how should I do it instead?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyTrackbar
{

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public delegate void StartDragHandler();
        public delegate void EndDragHandler();

        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Fires when user starts to drag.")]
        public event StartDragHandler StartDrag;
        [Category("Action")]
        [Description("Fires when user ends to drag.")]
        public event EndDragHandler EndDrag;

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void trackBar1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (StartDrag != null) {
                StartDrag();
            }

        }

        private void trackBar1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (EndDrag != null) {
                EndDrag();
            }
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestMyTrackBar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void userControl11_StartDrag()
        {
            // Work
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void userControl11_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Doesn't work !!!!!!!!!!!!
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: For people who want to check `InitializeComponent` even though I didn't modify it:

For custom control:

```
namespace MyTrackbar
{
    partial class UserControl1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.trackBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // trackBar1
            // 
            this.trackBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 17);
            this.trackBar1.Name = "trackBar1";
            this.trackBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(356, 45);
            this.trackBar1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.trackBar1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.trackBar1_MouseDown);
            this.trackBar1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.trackBar1_MouseUp);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 68);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(338, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // UserControl1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.trackBar1);
            this.Name = "UserControl1";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 150);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.trackBar1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar trackBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

For WinForm client:

```
namespace TestMyTrackBar
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.userControl11 = new MyTrackbar.UserControl1();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // userControl11
            // 
            this.userControl11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 39);
            this.userControl11.Name = "userControl11";
            this.userControl11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 114);
            this.userControl11.TabIndex = 0;
            this.userControl11.StartDrag += new MyTrackbar.UserControl1.StartDragHandler(this.userControl11_StartDrag);
            this.userControl11.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.userControl11_MouseUp);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 160);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(336, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(457, 231);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.userControl11);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private MyTrackbar.UserControl1 userControl11;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually using the `TrackBar` control, or have you built your own custom slider?

Comment: You're right, I just realize that it is when I embed the trackbar inside a custom control that it doesn't work.

Comment: @user310291 It cannot be a framework bug in the case it doesn't work liek you expect. If it was, .NET framework shall have more bugs than its SLOC count!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void userControl11_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Doesn't work !!!!!!!!!!!!
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

You should have used the EndDrag event, not MouseUp.

Comment: Sorry I was so tired that day I didn't see my obvious error :)

Answer (score 4):

**Before beginning, I want to clarify that the [answer provided by Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411172/is-this-a-net-framework-bug/4417384#4417384) already explains exactly the same thing I am about to. So, if you find this helpful, you should upvote his answer.**

However, it seems from the comment exchange that you aren't quite understanding what he's trying to say. Perhaps I can do a little better job explaining it, and maybe you'll have an easier time if understanding what's going on if you saw precisely what you had to change in your code.

Let's start out by assessing the current situation: Your textbox that is part of `userControl11` changes color properly when the user starts dragging the trackbar. However, the *second* textbox that is part of `Form1` does not turn back to white after you finish dragging the trackbar.

Your user control already raises two custom events `StartDrag` and `EndDrag`, with names that obviously indicate the current state. In `Form1`, you're handling the user control's `StartDrag` event and changing the color of the second textbox to red. But, instead of handling the `EndDrag` event to change the color back to white, you're handling the `MouseUp` event. This is why it's not working, and what Hans's answer was trying to tell you. **Instead, your form's code should look like this:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.userControl11.EndDrag += new MyTrackbar.UserControl1.EndDragHandler(this.userControl11_EndDrag);
   }

   private void userControl11_StartDrag()
   {
      // Works
      textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }

   private void userControl11_EndDrag()
   {
      // Now also works!
      textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
   }
}
```

You already understand that you need to handle the custom `StartDrag` event that you've raised, so it seems simple enough that you'd *also* need to handle the `EndDrag` event to achieve the desired effect.

But then, you might ask, "Why does the `MouseUp` event work inside of the user control, but *not* work inside of the form?!?" I assume this is what you're trying to argue is a bug in the .NET Framework. (Hint: It's *far* less likely that any of us will discover a true bug in the Framework than one of us is confused about *why* we're seeing the behavior that we are, or simply missing something obvious.)

The reason is because, inside the user control, you're handling the `MouseUp` event raised by the trackbar control (`trackBar1`). **But that event does not propagate upwards.** Just because the trackbar control raises the `MouseUp` event does *not* mean that the user control that contains it raises the same event. You seem to already know that with regards to the `MouseDown` event, and it's exactly the same thing with the `MouseUp` event.

No need to file a bug report with Microsoft, and no need for anyone to get their feelings hurt.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear the real problem, since the *InitializeComponent* implementation is completely missing from the example.

So, my answer is based on the following assertions:

- *UserControl1.trackBar1* is a *TrackBar*, *trackBar1_MouseDown* is subsciber of *UserControl1.trackBar1.MouseDown*, *trackBar1_MouseUp* is subsciber of *UserControl1.trackBar1.MouseUp*
- *Form1.userControl11* is a *UserControl1*, *userControl11_StartDrag()* is subscriber of *Form1.userControl11.StartDrag* event, *userControl11_MouseUp* is subscriber of *Form1.userControl11.MouseUp* event

It is correct that "doesn't work". Probably (and you should confirm it if it is) the event *Form1.userControl11.MouseUp* is never raised. Infact *Form1.userControl11.MouseUp* and *UserControl1.trackBar1.MouseUp* are not the same; infact *UserControl1* class expose the *EndDrag* event when its embedded Control *trackBar1* raises the *MouseUp* event.

So, the solution is to subscribe the UserControl1.EndDrag event, not the mouse up (as Hans Passant has stated), in order to reflect the correct behavior (supposed by me).

Comment: There's nothing special in InitializeComponent that's why I didn't post it. Now I can post it if you want to be sure there's nothing wrong there.

Comment: "the solution is to subscribe the EndDrag event" : it's not possible because this event doesn't exist for Trackbar control or did I miss something ?

Comment: (Answer edited) EndDrag event is declared in UserControl1 class, which is NOT a TrackBar. However, rereading the Hans Passant answer and comments, my answer state exactly the same things.